# What wrong am I doing in the below code? When I run this program I am getting error

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here according to my understanding, when I call the function 'func' then the positional argument '1' will align itself with 'a' and the keyword argument 'b' holding value 'Bee' will get assigned to 'b' (in def) and the values in the tuple will get unpacked and will get assigned to 'c' and 'd'.

I was expecting the o/p to be :

**1 Bee See Dee**

```
def func(a,b,c,d):
    print(a,b,c,d)

func(1, b= 'Bee', *('See','Dee'))
```

Actual error that i'm facing is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
func(1, b= 'Bee', *('See','Dee'))
TypeError: func() got multiple values for argument 'b'
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
func(1, 'Bee', *('See','Dee'))
```

Your original doesn't because `b` is specified as a keyword argument but also is the second positional argument (`'See'`).

Comment: Thanks @John for sharing your piece of code. I have one questions here now. Does arguments with * and ** considered as 'positional args' in python?

Comment: `*` indicates positional arguments; `**` is for keyword arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Consider putting attributes last, like this:

```
def func(a, b, c, d):
    print(a, b, c, d)

func(1, *('See', 'Dee'), d = 'Bee')
```